# Excel macro doesn't open on startup when called from MS Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access-2016

I know this issue has been hashed over many times but mine isn't addressed there.
I have an excel macro that is used for different projects. It's coded with variables, the variables are passed from MS Access and therefore, this macro can be used for any project.

Not only it runs fine when double clicked, but it also works for other projects.
The only thing I can think of that sets this project apart is that in the same procedure, another excel file is called a few steps before.
But after run, that excel instance is closed (i checked, it really does close, i close it by

```
SET myexcelinstance = nothing
```

What can it be? I can double click on the file for this project as well and everything is created without error.

But when called from Ms Access, it just opens like a regular file

edit: adding the macro

this is in a separate module

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub auto_open()
MainProcedure
End Sub
```

this is the main procedure, in a separate module

```
Option Explicit

Public x      As Integer
Public PadLength As Integer

Public LastRow As Long
Public LastRow4 As Long
Public LastRow2 As Long

Public CurPath As String

Public ProjectName As String
Public FormattedDate As String
Public RunDate As Date
Public ReportPath As String
Public MonthlyPath As String

Public TableName As String
Public FinalExcelFileName As String
Public ExcelFileName As String
Public ExcelSheetName As String
Public ExcelTemplate As String
Public ExcelPasteTo As String
Public TemplateFileName As String
Public SheetToSelect As String

Public FSO
Public oShell As Object
Public iResponse As Integer
Public CurCell, CurRange As Range


Public CurRowNum As Long
Public LastRowOfSection As Long
Public FirstRowOfSection As Long

Public CurLastColumn As Variant
Public CurLastRow As Long
  
Public CurFileName As String
Public CurSheetName As String

Public Sub MainProcedure()

    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    CurPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"

    'this is to deselect sheets
    Sheets("QFilesToExportEMail").Select

    Sheets("QReportDates").Activate

    FormattedDate = Range("A2").Value
    RunDate = Range("B2").Value
    ReportPath = Range("C2").Value
    MonthlyPath = Range("D2").Value
    ProjectName = Range("E2").Value
         
    Windows(ProjectName & ".xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("QFilesToExportEMail").Select
    'Ctrl + Shift + End
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    

    Dim i     As Integer

    CurRowNum = 2

    Set CurRange = Sheets("QFilesToExportEMail").Range("B" & CurRowNum & ":B" & LastRow) '''''sets the range to use

    For Each CurCell In CurRange                 ''''checks each cell in range
                     
        If CurCell <> "" Then                    '''''will only do something if the cell is not blank
                                   
            Windows(ProjectName & ".xlsm").Activate
            Sheets("QFilesToExportEMail").Select
                                   
            ExcelFileName = Range("B" & CurRowNum).Value
            FinalExcelFileName = Range("B" & CurRowNum).Value
            LastRowOfSection = Sheets("QFilesToExportEMail").Range("B" & CurRowNum & ":B" & LastRow).Find(what:=ExcelFileName, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Row
            'FirstRowOfSection = Sheets("QFilesToExportEMail").Range("B" & CurRowNum & ":B" & LastRow).Find(what:=ExcelFileName).Row
            TemplateFileName = Range("F" & CurRowNum).Value
                                   
            FirstRowOfSection = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("QFilesToExportEMail").Columns(2).Find(ExcelFileName).Row

            TableName = Range("A" & CurRowNum).Value
            ExcelSheetName = Range("C" & CurRowNum).Value
                                                        
            If ExcelSheetName = "" Then
                ExcelSheetName = TableName
            End If
                                                        
            If CurRowNum = FirstRowOfSection Then
                SheetToSelect = ExcelSheetName
            End If
                                   
            If IsNull(TemplateFileName) Or TemplateFileName = "" Then
                Workbooks.Add
            Else
                Workbooks.Open CurPath & TemplateFileName
            End If
                                   
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs MonthlyPath & FinalExcelFileName
                                   
            For i = CurRowNum To LastRowOfSection
                                                                 
                Windows(ProjectName & ".xlsm").Activate
                Sheets("QFilesToExportEMail").Select
                                                        
                TableName = Range("A" & i).Value
                ExcelSheetName = Range("C" & i).Value
                ExcelTemplate = Range("D" & i).Value
                ExcelPasteTo = Range("E" & i).Value
                                                        
                If ExcelSheetName = "" Then
                    ExcelSheetName = TableName
                End If
                                                        
                If ExcelTemplate = "format" Then
                                                                      
                    Windows(FinalExcelFileName).Activate
                    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(after:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)).Name = ExcelSheetName
                                                                                                                                            
                    Windows(ProjectName & ".xlsm").Activate
                    Sheets(TableName).Select
                                                                       
                    CurLastColumn = MyColumnLetter(Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count)
                    CurLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                                                                      
                    Range("A1:" & CurLastColumn & CurLastRow).Select
                    Selection.Copy
                                                                      
                    Windows(FinalExcelFileName).Activate
                    Sheets(ExcelSheetName).Select
                    Range(ExcelPasteTo).Select
                    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                                                                      
                    FormatBasics
                                                                      
                ElseIf ExcelTemplate = "" Then
                                                                      
                    Windows(ProjectName & ".xlsm").Activate
                    Sheets(TableName).Select
                                                                      
                    CurLastColumn = MyColumnLetter(Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count)
                    CurLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                                                                      
                    Range("A2:" & CurLastColumn & CurLastRow).Select
                    Selection.Copy
                                                                      
                    Windows(FinalExcelFileName).Activate
                    Sheets(ExcelSheetName).Select
                    Range(ExcelPasteTo).Select
                    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                    '
                    '                                                                          Dim SearchString As String
                    '                                                                        Dim SearchRange As Range, cl As Range
                    '                                                                        Dim FirstFound As String
                    '                                                                        Dim sh As Worksheet
                    '
                    '                                                                        ' Set Search value
                    '                                                                        SearchString = "N/A"
                    '                                                                        Application.FindFormat.Clear
                    '                                                                        ' loop through all sheets
                    '                                                                        For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
                    '                                                                            ' Find first instance on sheet
                    '                                                                            Set cl = sh.Cells.Find(What:=SearchString, _
                    '                                                                                After:=sh.Cells(1, 1), _
                    '                                                                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    '                                                                                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    '                                                                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    '                                                                                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    '                                                                                MatchCase:=False, _
                    '                                                                                SearchFormat:=False)
                    '                                                                            If Not cl Is Nothing Then
                    '                                                                                ' if found, remember location
                    '                                                                                FirstFound = cl.Address
                    '                                                                                ' format found cell
                    '                                                                                Do
                    '                                                                                    cl.Font = "Calibri"
                    '                                                                                    cl.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                    '                                                                                    ' find next instance
                    '                                                                                    Set cl = sh.Cells.FindNext(After:=cl)
                    '                                                                                    ' repeat until back where we started
                    '                                                                                Loop Until FirstFound = cl.Address
                    '                                                                            End If
                    '                                                                        Next
                                                                      
                                                                      
                ElseIf ExcelTemplate Like "*TEMPLATE*" Then
                                                                      
                    Windows(ProjectName & ".xlsm").Activate
                                                                      
                    Sheets(ExcelTemplate).Copy after:=Workbooks(FinalExcelFileName).Sheets(1)
                    ActiveSheet.Name = ExcelSheetName
                    ActiveSheet.Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count) 'moves it to the end
                                                                                                                                            
                    Sheets(ExcelSheetName).Select
                                                                      
                    Windows(ProjectName & ".xlsm").Activate
                    Sheets(TableName).Select
                                                                      
                    CurLastColumn = MyColumnLetter(Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count)
                    CurLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                                                                      
                    Range("A2:" & CurLastColumn & CurLastRow).Select
                    Selection.Copy
                                                                      
                    Windows(FinalExcelFileName).Activate
                    Sheets(ExcelSheetName).Select
                    Range(ExcelPasteTo).Select
                    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                                                                      
                End If
                                                        
                Range(ExcelPasteTo).Select
                                                        
            Next i
                                                                 
            If LastRowOfSection < LastRow Then
                CurRowNum = LastRowOfSection + 1
            Else
                CurRowNum = LastRowOfSection
            End If
                                            
        End If
                     
        Windows(FinalExcelFileName).Activate
                     
        If CheckSheet("Sheet1") Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Delete
        End If
                     
        Sheets(SheetToSelect).Select
                                   
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
                     
        If LastRowOfSection >= LastRow Then
            Exit For
        End If
                     
    Next

    CurSheetName = ""

    Windows(ProjectName & ".xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("QFilesToExportEMail").Select
    'Ctrl + Shift + End
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


    Set CurRange = Sheets("QFilesToExportEMail").Range("A2:A" & LastRow) '''''sets the range to use
    For Each CurCell In CurRange                 ''''checks each cell in range
        If CurCell <> "" Then                    '''''will only do something if the cell is not blank

            CurSheetName = CurCell

            If CheckSheet(CurSheetName) Then
                Sheets(CurSheetName).Delete
            End If

        End If
    Next
   
    Sheets("QFilesToExportEMail").Delete
    Sheets("QReportDates").Delete
                                             
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub

Function CheckSheet(ByVal sCurSheetName As String) As Boolean

    Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim bReturn As Boolean

    For Each oSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If oSheet.Name = sCurSheetName Then
            bReturn = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next oSheet

    CheckSheet = bReturn

End Function

Public Function MyColumnLetter(MyNumber As Long) As String
    If MyNumber > 26 Then
        MyColumnLetter = Chr(Int((MyNumber - 1) / 26) + 64) & Chr(((MyNumber - 1) Mod 26) + 65)
    Else
        MyColumnLetter = Chr(MyNumber + 64)
    End If
End Function

Public Function xlLastCol(Optional WorkCurSheetName As String) As Long 'finds the last populated col in a worksheet
    If WorkCurSheetName = vbNullString Then WorkCurSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
    With Worksheets(WorkCurSheetName)
        On Error Resume Next
        xlLastCol = .Cells.Find("*", .Cells(1), xlFormulas, xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
        If Err <> 0 Then xlLastCol = 0
    End With
End Function

Public Function QueryDB(ByVal connectionString As String, ByVal Target As Excel.Range, ByVal SQL As String)
    Dim qt    As Excel.QueryTable
    Dim ws    As Excel.Worksheet
    Set ws = Target.Parent
    Set qt = ws.QueryTables.Add(connectionString, Target, SQL)
    qt.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End Function

'=====================================================================
'The following function will left pad a string with a specified
'character. It accepts a base string which is to be left padded with
'characters, a character to be used as the pad character, and a
'length which specifies the total length of the padded result.
'=====================================================================
Function Lpad(MyValue$, MyPadCharacter$, MyPaddedLength%)

    PadLength = MyPaddedLength - Len(MyValue)
    Dim PadString As String
    For x = 1 To PadLength
        PadString = PadString & MyPadCharacter
    Next
    Lpad = PadString + MyValue

End Function

'=====================================================================
'The following function will right pad a string with a specified
'character. It accepts a base string which is to be right padded with
'characters, a character to be used as the pad character, and a
'length which specifies the total length of the padded result.
'=====================================================================
Function Rpad(MyValue$, MyPadCharacter$, MyPaddedLength%)

    PadLength = MyPaddedLength - Len(MyValue)
    Dim PadString As String
    For x = 1 To PadLength
        PadString = MyPadCharacter & PadString
    Next
    Rpad = MyValue + PadString

End Function

Public Function FormatBasics()

    Dim x     As Long
    Dim FormatColumnLetter, FormatColumnName As String

    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled

    Cells.Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .Size = 11
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ColorIndex = 1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
    End With
    
    Range("A1:" & MyColumnLetter(xlLastCol) & "1").Select
    
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    
    With Selection.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = 2
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = -0.149998474074526
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    
    Selection.AutoFilter
    
    Rows("2:2").Select
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
         
         
    For x = 1 To xlLastCol
         
        FormatColumnLetter = MyColumnLetter(x)
        FormatColumnName = StrConv(Range(FormatColumnLetter & "1").Value, vbLowerCase)
         
        Range(FormatColumnLetter & "1").Value = StrConv(Range(FormatColumnLetter & "1").Value, vbProperCase)

        If FormatColumnName = "factypedesc" Then
            Range(FormatColumnLetter & "1").Value = "FacTypeDesc"
        ElseIf FormatColumnName = "facsubtypedesc" Then
            Range(FormatColumnLetter & "1").Value = "FacSubTypeDesc"
        ElseIf FormatColumnName = "facsubtype" Then
            Range(FormatColumnLetter & "1").Value = "FacSubType"
        ElseIf FormatColumnName = "mpinetworkcode" Then
            Range(FormatColumnLetter & "1").Value = "Network"
        ElseIf FormatColumnName = "mpicontractid" Then
            Range(FormatColumnLetter & "1").Value = "ContractNumber"
        ElseIf FormatColumnName = "dob" Or FormatColumnName = "dateofbirth" Then
            Range(FormatColumnLetter & "1").Value = "DOB"
        ElseIf FormatColumnName = "deanumber" Then
            Range(FormatColumnLetter & "1").Value = "DEANumber"
        End If     
          
         
    Next x
    
    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

    Columns("A:" & MyColumnLetter(xlLastCol)).Sort key1:=Range("A2"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

    Range("A2").Select

End Function
```

Comment: Can you share a bit more of the macro?

Comment: Sure!! Will update the post now

Comment: so, i'm wrong. my first excel macro is still in memory, would this prevent this one from opening? i mean, i'm not sure what exactly is in memory, this file or what but there's an open instance

Comment: omg, i'm an idiot, i'm using the same instance for both files. i'm sure this is the problem, let me try

Answer (score 0):

just in case someone else is struggling, in my case, in MS Access i was doing the following

```
    Set ExcelApp2 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

some code

        ExcelApp2.Workbooks.Open CurPath & "MatchLoad.xlsm", True
        ExcelApp2.Visible = True
        ExcelApp2.Quit 

some code

        ExcelApp2.Workbooks.Open CurPath & "MatchLoad2.xlsm", True
        ExcelApp2.Visible = True
        ExcelApp2.Quit
```

as you can see, i was creating an instance, then reusing the same instance later. for some reason, this prevents opening the next macro on startup, if the first one is sitting in memory. i do not know why but it seems to be the case.
So, for the second xlsm file, it would open, but the startup macro wouldn't run.

i later added

```
Set ExcelApp2 = Nothing
```

and of course was getting an error, since the instance was closed, but i was trying to open another file under it.

Now I'm doing the following

```
Set ExcelApp2 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
ExcelApp2.Workbooks.Open CurPath & "MatchLoad.xlsm", True
ExcelApp2.Visible = True
ExcelApp2.Quit 
Set ExcelApp2 = Nothing 

some code

Set ExcelApp2 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
ExcelApp2.Workbooks.Open CurPath & "MatchLoad2.xlsm", True
ExcelApp2.Visible = True
ExcelApp2.Quit 
Set ExcelApp2 = Nothing
```

And it works.

however, there's still 1 puzzle left. even with the

```
Set ExcelApp2 = Nothing
```

i'm still seeing excel instances in memory. any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Hmm for me the second chunk of code works just fine without changing its format from what you have here. However you won't see it release from memory until the `= Nothing` line

Comment: But it doesnt leave the memory!! I see an instance there. I guess it doesn't matter that much, since it works now but I have a lot of programs running at once and end up with 20-30 instances. I will record what happens and will send you a link to the video. For you, it leaves the memory?

Comment: Wait, are you saying that you can open 2 xlsm files with the code I have above? For me, with that code, the 2nd file would open but the macro on it wouldn't run.